# No route found for "GET /register"

Tags: symfony-3.4

I tried to use to get /register but it's not showing.

> No route found for "GET /register" 404 page not found.

Here is my code routing.yml:

```
user_registration:
    path:     /register
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Registration:register }
```

Please tell how to overcome this error? Thanks

Comment: Run `php bin/console debug:router` command in console to see all route which are available in your project.

Comment: ya i checked.accordingly i set here in routing.yml